# Add Custom Field in Product in WP Admin and send to Order Webhook

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

Friends,

I am new to WP and WC and pls help.

I have a Product Page with variations. What I am trying to do is to create a Custom Text Box in the Advanced tab of the Product Page where I can enter the Image Name for (eg. RedShirt_xxl.jpg) against Each Product. When someone places an Order, the file name should be sent to Webhook along with the Order JSON.

For eg. each product there are 4 colors and 4 sizes, and for each combination (like Blue Color and XL) I need to specify a filename for each product and this Name (for eg. Blue_xl.jpb or red_xl.jpg or green_xxl.jpg) should be sent to the Order Webhook to be processed

The complexity is for each variation like Blue, Red or Orange, the file name changes and I am stuck on a how to add filenames to each variation.

Or if there is some other better method pls advice.

Comment: What are you planning to do with that? You can add custom images to each product variation in WC.

Comment: Hi, I have already added the custom images to each product variation.  In addition to the image I need to send the file name to the Webhook for each variation. As the name will be different for each variation

Comment: With webhook do you mean outside the WP server?

Comment: yes, when an order is made by the customer, he selects the variations for each product. WC Sends this Order details via webhook and want to inlucde the selected image and the image name to webhook

Comment: Could you add the code that sends the request to your webhook after an order is placed?

Comment: When an order is placed WC automatically sends the Order details via webhook, it is a built in functionality

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112458/discussion-between-tgs-and-himad).